# Have script input carried over after script runs ssh and sudo command

Tags: ssh, scp

I am trying to create a script that I can run on the landing server that takes user input and then carries the input into the next server and sudo change.

Scenario:
Log into first server
run script
Requires user to input data
Script takes input data and runs ssh into next server
Sudo command run
scp copies file(s)

Problem:
After the script runs ssh command it doesn't continue running the script at the next server.  I exit back to the 1st server and then it runs the next command.
Basically the script info doesn't carry over to the next server and sudo user

What I have now/want to happen:

```
read -p 'Enter customer name: ' cname
read -p 'Enter transferring file name: ' flname
read -p 'Enter your username: ' uname

ssh server.com
sudo -u "$cname"_sh -H -s 
scp ""$cname"_scp@files.server.net:download/$flname" $flname
scp $flname ""$uname"@1stServer.net:/export/home/$uname/download/$flname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your script gets executed sequentially and once you execute the command

ssh server.com

then effectively you login into the shell of remote server.com and you don't have any more commands to execute.